# T-SQL - get total length of stay and first day of stay

Tags: t-sql

Data is like the following:

[image: Test Data]

I need to know how long each client has stayed with us (in days), and the date they first started staying with us.

Comment: Please consider supplying your data in a digestible format instead of using an image, as well as what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ClientID, sum(DATEDIFF(day, StartDate, EndDate)) as [LengthOfStay], Min(StartDate) 
FROM dbo.MyTable GROUP BY ClientID
```

Note: This will give you the total number of days stayed per `ClientID` as well as each `ClientID`'s minimum `StartDate`. It is important to note that the `StartDate` and `EndDate` columns should be stored in `datetime` format

Comment: This works assuming there is no overlap (e.g. a client booking two rooms). If overlap is possible, it's a little more complicated and would probably require reshaping the data.

Comment: In the table provided ClientID is not unique which causes me to assume that the primary key would have to be some kind of ReservationID - each record has to describe something, right? If each row isn't a reservation than what else could it be? However, if each row is a Reservation, than this would work even if there is overlap.